# explode function from database

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP app for expense records approval.
When a user submits a record this record should be approved by different roles coming from table `'users'` for example, the record should be approved by 'Manager', 'Finance', 'ccOapprover' and 'observer', all those are roles for different users in a column.
What I want is to have some users with more than one role for example JohnDoe to be 'ccapprover' and 'observer'.
My idea was to separate those via commas for the specific user like `'ccapprover, observer'` and to use `explode` in PHP but something is wrong with my code.

Here is my process_approval.php

```
include 'session.php';
include 'config.php';


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $reportId = $_POST['report_id'];
    $approval = $_POST['approval'];
    $allowedRoles = ['manager', 'finance', 'ccapprover', 'observer'];
    if (in_array($user_type, $allowedRoles)) {
        
        $approvedRoles = explode(', ', $user_type);

        $approverColumn = '';
        $statusColumn = '';
        $dateColumn = '';

        foreach ($approvedRoles as $approvedRole) {
            switch ($approvedRole) {
                case 'manager':
                    $approverColumn = 'mng_approver';
                    $statusColumn = 'mng_approver_status';
                    $dateColumn = 'mng_approval_date';
                    break;
                case 'finance':
                    $approverColumn = 'finance_approval';
                    $statusColumn = 'finance_approval_status';
                    $dateColumn = 'finance_approval_date';
                    break;
                case 'ccapprover':
                    $approverColumn = 'cc_approver';
                    $statusColumn = 'cc_approver_status';
                    $dateColumn = 'cc_approval_date';
                    break;
                case 'observer':
                    $approverColumn = 'observer';
                    $statusColumn = 'observer_status';
                    $dateColumn = 'observer_approval_date';
                    break;
            }

            if (!empty($approverColumn)) {
                
                $updateQuery = "UPDATE expenses SET $approverColumn = :email, $statusColumn = :status, $dateColumn = NOW() WHERE id = :report_id";

                try {
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($updateQuery);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $approval);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':report_id', $reportId);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    echo "Approval/Rejection recorded successfully for role: $approvedRole<br>";
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Error recording approval/rejection: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Invalid approver role: $approvedRole<br>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        
        echo "Unauthorized access.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No POST data received.";
}
```

When I set it to some user `'ccapprover, observer'` he is not able to approve both and always getting `Unauthorized access`

Where is my mistake?

Edit: In session.php I am sorting variable
`$user_type = $_SESSION['type'];` which is getting type from db

Comment: You have `if (in_array($user_type, $allowedRoles)) {` which will never be true if you have more than one role in your `$user_type` (string) variable

Comment: This is a bad idea, which will cause you more and more headaches as time goes on. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), and then learn the basics of relational database design and normalisation, so that you store your user roles using a correctly designed many-to-many relationship in your database, with a separate table to represent the links between users and roles.

Comment: Have you outputted the values and seen what they are? `something is wrong` is a bad description of your issue. Please do some more debugging so we can assist. We don't have any of your data so can't run the code. Also, likely related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad. I would not want to have to have all these variable columns

Comment: P.S. Your column-switching code based on the approver type is also a signal of a denormalised database schema. Again, the approvals should be in a separate table, with a foreign key relationship back to the expenses table, so you can easily add approval records without needing to use a different query every time. Again, a properly designed database will also cause you less headaches later on, e.g. when you need to extract an audit trail or do reporting, searching etc. on the approval records. It's a good idea to learn how to design a database _before_ trying to design a database :-)

Comment: *"My idea was to separate those via commas"*  Having serialized datas goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS. Think about [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), using 3 tables : `users`, `roles` and `users_roles`

Comment: Thanks for the guides team, I understand that and in my plan is in near future to rework this app in a better way, just now looking for "quick and dirty" solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments about database design mentioned above.  However, to fix your immediate problem you could change the following code:

```
$allowedRoles = ['manager', 'finance', 'ccapprover', 'observer'];
if (in_array($user_type, $allowedRoles)) {
    
    $approvedRoles = explode(', ', $user_type);

    // ...
```

to:

```
$allowedRoles = ['manager', 'finance', 'ccapprover', 'observer'];
$userRoles = explode(', ', $user_type);
$approvedRoles = array_interesect($allowedRoles, $userRoles);
if (!empty($approvedRoles)) {
    
    // ...
```

This should answer your question.  But I echo the concerns others have raised - this approach is going to cause you more problems in the long term.

Comment: Thank you @Rob Eyre. 
This is working. for sure I will consider reconstruction of the app but your idea as a "quick and dirty solution" is working.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is wrong, because we do not know where `$user_type` is coming from. Nevertheless I can still already answer that those three lines of code seem to be wrong:

```
   $allowedRoles = ['manager', 'finance', 'ccapprover', 'observer'];
   if (in_array($user_type, $allowedRoles)) {
        
        $approvedRoles = explode(', ', $user_type);
```

If you use `explode` like this on `$user_type`, it has to be a string, potentially containing `,`  like your example `'ccapprover, observer'`. If `$user_type` looks like this, your if clause will always evaluate to false, since that string is not in the array `$allowedRoles`. Therefor you always land in the else branch giving you the described error.

You would have to explode the string before the if clause and change your logic starting from there.